# Pandas read JSON causes values to convert into scientific notation

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, scientific-notation

I am working with a pandas Dataframe in which one column contains a 27 digit number. I converted the Dataframe into a JSON array using:

```
pd.read_json(df, orient='split')
```

When converting the JSON array back into a Dataframe, I used:

```
 pd.read_json(df, orient='split')
```

However, in the conversion, the values were converted to a scientific notation.

```
Actual: 8.123456e+27
Expected: 8123456342700123300640123456
```

Is there a way I can get around this? Apologies for only providing a sudo code, I'm working with confidential information.

Comment: What type (int or float) do you expect that field to be?

Comment: What is/are the dtype(s) of the column(s) with the scientific notated numbers?

Comment: In the original dataframe, the values were an `object`, but the scientific notated numbers are now a `float64`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a work around by including an additional parameter within `pd.read_json`

```
pd.read_json(df, orient='split', dtype = {"column_name": object})
```

[I used this as reference](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18842)

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%d' % x)
```

For example, with this sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['8123456342700123300640123456']],
                   index=['row'],
                   columns=['col'])
print(df.dtypes)
dx = df.to_json(orient='split')
dg = pd.read_json(dx, orient='split')
print(dg)
print(dg.dtypes)
```

Output: (Notice `float64` for `col`)

```
col    object
dtype: object
                             col
row 8123456342700123332831870976
col    float64
dtype: object
```

To change it back to object, you can use

```
dg = pd.read_json(dx, orient='split').astype(object)
print(dg)
print(dg.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
                             col
row 8123456342700123332831870976
col    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me :/
I see that the dtype reads `object`, but the value printed is still in scientific notation. 
I executed the code as such.
`>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%d' % x)` 
`>>> var = pd.read_json(df, orient='split').astype(object)`

Comment: [Repl.it Code](https://repl.it/@ShivamSingh2/PandasExample) This is the working code. Can you check the pandas version?

Comment: I found a work around, thank you so much for your help!